# Error 500 Internal Server Error occurred on Tuleap Mylyn connector

Tags: eclipse-plugin, server, mylyn, tuleap

I am using Tuleap as my Application Life-cycle Management tool. I am trying to connect to my Tuleap server from Eclipse Mylyn connector (tuleap plugin) to have my trackers available in eclipse planning perspective.

While I'm trying to connect to a tuleap server using my username and password I get following error:

```
http://<tuleap-server-address>/plugins/tracker/?tracker=17
```